# What is the definition of "lexically-ordered" base64 and why is RFCC-1940 apparently the canonical reference?

Tags: java, base64, netty, rfc

Today I was reading the documentation for Netty's [Base64Dialect](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/base64/Base64Dialect.html) class.

It includes a dialect called `ORDERED`, of which it says, somewhat briefly:

> Special "ordered" dialect of Base64 described in RFC1940.

To cut to the chase, I can't find any definition of what this is, and includes an erroneous reference which seems to replicated all over the internet.

Instead of [RFC-1940](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1940.html), the document actually links to [RFCC-1940](http://www.faqs.org/qa/rfcc-1940.html), which apparently is a "reader comment", and a nonsensical one at that:

> ## RFC 920: whkpiy clujzis brkyh dwojfmz jydwq hrnwcgklt fsltaiu
>
> Comment by lsnxkrjo sxavymwpg
>
> Submitted on 10/26/2006
>
> Related RFC: [RFC-920](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc920.html)

Now [RFC-920](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc920.html) appears to have nothing to do with base 64:

> ## Domain requirements
>
> This memo restates and refines the requirements on establishing a
> Domain first described in [RFC-881](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc881.html).  It adds considerable detail
> to that discussion, and introduces the limited set of top level
> domains.

Is [RFC-1940](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1940.html) relevant? Skimming, no I can't see any base 64 encoding definitions here:

> ## Source Demand Routing: Packet Format and Forwarding Specification (Version 1).
>
> The purpose of SDRP is to support source-initiated selection of
> routes to complement the route selection provided by existing routing
> protocols for both inter-domain and intra-domain routes. [...]

In fact, searching the web for "rfcc 1940 ordered base64" finds this same URL in lots of other documentation, but sadly no explanation of "lexically ordered base 64".

Is there a legitimate definition of this anywhere? And why hasn't anyone else noticed this URL refers to nonsense?

Comment: Seems the link had some sensible content once upon a time: https://web.archive.org/web/20080602210354/http://www.faqs.org/qa/rfcc-1940.html . Unfortunately, it was vandalized some time between 2 June and 21 August 2008, and the original has not been restored.

Comment: For the record: "base64 encoding is 33% more compact than Hex encoding, but lexicographical order is not preserved. Though this property could be very useful when used inside filenames or URLs.   A simple reordering of the proposed alternate base64 encoding table would just do the trick"

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a "legitimate definition" of ordered Base64.  (At time of writing this, it is not even mentioned in the Wikipedia page on [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).)

If you treat the code as a specification(!), ordered Base64 is a variant in which the alphabet has been reordered into ascending ASCII order.  This means that the natural ordering for ordered Base64 is the same as the natural ordering for the corresponding byte sequence.

---

Is it a problem that there isn't a specification for ordered Base64?

Probably not.

- In reality the RFCs that "specify" the different variants of Base64 (and Base32 / Base16) are actually more of an attempt to describe the  variants rather than specify them.  And the same applies to the Wikipedia article.
- From what I can tell (google searches), the ordered Base64 variant is rarely used.
- The Base64 [implementation](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) that introduced the ordered variant is legacy code.  (It hasn't been changed in the last 8 years).  New Java code that requires Base64 encoding / decoding capability should be using the standard Java [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class introduced in Java 8.

But it is concerning that the javadocs you linked to (and others!) all refer to a nonsense page.  That page probably had a legitimate description at some point, but it looks like it has been vandalized.

Comment: My current best guess is that Netty and everyone else imported [Robert Harder's Public Domain Base64 Encoder/Decoder](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) wholesale before Java 8 introduced a Base64 implementation, and that contained the `ORDERED` dialect for reasons.